# testing-library/react-hooks calling a function that change the state

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I tried everything but still for some reason the react state doesn't change, what is I am missing or what is the alternative approach?
Code:

```
export const useCounter = (): UseCounterResult => {
  const session = useSession();
  const [list, setList] = useState<Customer[]>([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getApiClient(session).listCustomers();
      setList((response?.customers || []));
      setCounter(response.todayCount);
      setLimit(response.dailyLimit);
    })();
  }, [session]);

  function addToList(newItem: Customer) {
    setList((list) => [...newItem,...list]);
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  }

  return {counter, limit, list, addToList};
};
```

And the UT I tried but doesn't work:

```
  it.only("should add to list", async () => {
    // arrange
    (getApiClient as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
      listCustomers: async () => ({
        customers: [],
        todayCount: 1,
        dailyLimit: 5,
      }),
    });
    // act
    const { result, unmount, waitForNextUpdate, rerender } =
      renderHook(useCounter);
    act(() => {
      result.current.addToList({
        mobileNumber: "John",
        receiverName: "+61456789123",
      });
    });
    // await waitForNextUpdate();
    // assert
    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.counter).toBe(2));
    unmount();
  });
```

I tried without wrapping into `act` and instead calling `waitForNextUpdate` after it, still didn't work, `result.current.counter` is 1 instead of `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `addToList` until after you know that your async API call inside your `useEffect` completes - because when that call completes it will overwrite the state that may have been set by an `addToList` call if the async call happened to be in progress.

You can do that by asserting that `result.current.dailyLimit` contains the value returned from the API.

After your test has asserted that, then go ahead and make your call to `addToList` and perform your subsequent assertion

```
  it.only("should add to list", async () => {
    // arrange
    (getApiClient as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
      listCustomers: async () => ({
        customers: [],
        todayCount: 1,
        dailyLimit: 5,
      }),
    });
    // act
    const { result, unmount, waitForNextUpdate, rerender } =
      renderHook(useCounter);

    // now you know your async call has resolved
    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.dailyLimit).toEqual(5));

    // call add to list - you don't need to wrap it in `act` because you have `waitFor` right after
    result.current.addToList({
      mobileNumber: "John",
      receiverName: "+61456789123",
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.counter).toBe(2));
    unmount();
  });
```